# Python: how to avoid loop to convert in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df:
      y     m   d   val
0   2013    10  1   33.5
1   2013    10  2   37.1
2   2013    10  3   25.9
3   2013    10  4   31.3
4   2013    10  5   35.3
5   2013    10  6   55.4
6   2013    10  7   29.5
7   2013    10  8   31.3
8   2013    10  9   27.7
9   2013    10  10  25.9
```

where `y`, `m`, `d` correspond to year, month and day respectively. I want to aggregate them and convert to a `datetime`.

```
df['date'] =  0
for v in df.index:
    df['date'][v] = datetime.datetime(df.y[v], df.m[v], df.d[v])
```

I am wondering which is the best way to avoid that loop

Comment: I think apply is your friend: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Answer (score 4):

From [docstring](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/edit/master/pandas/tseries/tools.py):

```
Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys can be
common abbreviations like ['year', 'month', 'day', 'minute', 'second',
'ms', 'us', 'ns']) or plurals of the same

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                       'month': [2, 3],
                       'day': [4, 5]})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df)
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Code:

```
In [135]: pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns={'y':'Year','m':'Month','d':'Day'}).iloc[:, :3])
Out[135]:
0   2013-10-01
1   2013-10-02
2   2013-10-03
3   2013-10-04
4   2013-10-05
5   2013-10-06
6   2013-10-07
7   2013-10-08
8   2013-10-09
9   2013-10-10
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
pd.to_datetime((df['y']*10000 + df['m']*100 + df['d']).astype(str))
Out: 
0   2013-10-01
1   2013-10-02
2   2013-10-03
3   2013-10-04
4   2013-10-05
5   2013-10-06
6   2013-10-07
7   2013-10-08
8   2013-10-09
9   2013-10-10
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```